# How to clean up Rx Subscription and Observable to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I'm working on a project that uses Rx Java subscriptions and observables frequently and I am very new to the concept. I was wondering what the best practice is for disposing of them. Currently I am just nulling out the subscriptions/observables in the `doOnUnsubscribe()` function as well as using `takeUntil()` with a `PublishSubject` to trigger a disconnect for the observables. Is this the proper way to clean up these references or is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a subscription ends naturally, via `onCompleted()` or `onError()`, the subscription is cleaned up. If you use:

```
Subscription sub = observable.subscribe( value -> doSomeStuff() );
```

then calling `sub.unsubscribe()` will release the resources.

You can also use a `CompositeSubscription` to hold all of your outstanding subscriptions. When you perform `clear()` on the composite, then all contained subscriptions will be unsubscribed and removed; when you `unsubscribe()` from the composite, then all subscriptions contained will be unsubscribed, and then the composite subscription itself will be unsubscribed.

Nulling out resources may not do what you want nor is it needed, especially if there are multiple subscriptions.

Comment: What about observables?

Comment: If you have a `Subject` that is subscribed to another observable, you may want to unsubscribe it. Otherwise, an observable is a passive object until it is subscribed to. With no subscriptions, a cold observable does nothing. A hot observable will try to find any subscribers and emit data to them, but otherwise won't be consuming resources.